# TypeScript definition, how to constraint differently for a param of function, by matching certain value in param

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a function need to define, such a function's usage can be simplify as below:

```js
test({ flag: 1, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 1 }) // not ok
test({ flag: 2, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 2 }) // is ok
```

- if `flag` is number `1`, payload must be appear
- if `flag` is not number `1`, payload is not required

I was thinking of using function overloading to write such definiton. but turns out all definitions of function overloading is 'Or' relationship, and i can not define a type that exclude `1` from `number`

```js
interface TestFunc {
  (data: { flag: 1, payload: number }): void
  // can I exclude 1 from number ?
  (data: { flag: number, payload?: number }): void
}

const test: TestFunc = (data) => {
  // ...
}

test({ flag: 1 }) // it should report type error
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `extends` to detect if your `flag` property equals to `1` - and correspondingly build the part with `payload`:

```
interface Payload {
    payload: number;
}

function test<T extends number>(data: { flag: T } & (T extends 1 ? Payload : Partial<Payload>)): void {

}

test({ flag: 1, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 1 }) // not ok
test({ flag: 2, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 2 }) // is ok
```

You can play with this example at the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmyA3gFDLnIAOmuBAXMiAK4C2ARtANwkC%20JJMJiARhgOEMkgBnMAB4AKsggAPSCHxTGrDlAB8ACnxwwcBkWQwscAOYNFPZADJk%20xSrUbkARmQB%20NDR4hAzoUKJwWLLo2EG6AJRxDABuOMCEpLz80mD65pY2DF4ANFSB9N4ATADMyDxxyAD0DcjAmjgA1iTZuRZWtt619U2MOGDIHV0QMj35-RUl1DHlXtWDjc2t453deX0MFWvDmx1AA).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve smth similar to `negation`:

```js
type NotOne<T extends number> = T extends 1 ? never : T;

type WithOne = {
  flag: 1,
  payload: number
}

type WithoutOne<T extends number> = {
  flag: NotOne<T>,
  payload?: number
}

type Data<T extends number> = WithOne | WithoutOne<T>

interface TestFunc {
  (data: WithOne): void
  <T extends number>(data: WithoutOne<T>): void
}

const test: TestFunc = <T extends number>(data: Data<T>) => {
}


test({ flag: 1, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 1 }) // not ok
test({ flag: 2, payload: 123 }) // is ok
test({ flag: 2 }) // is ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.9.7#code/FAFwngDgpgBAcgexAeQHZQDwBUZQB4hSoAmAzjKgK4C2ARlAE4B8MAvDDvoSeQIwwB%20ClABujGAC4OAbmChIsAOoBLEAAs0sdgG9gMGADMANgEMA5lN4AaPTAgmwRhCeJSqdRsAC%20c8NBgq6giUKOjYuAREZBQ09MxsMLr6xuZSiKGYWEw2%20vaOzsQCbrGePvL%20ACImICbhXFHk7nEs7IEa6DAAPgGqasEZ2ExyyqiEDAYmAMawWFCkIABilKiTibYAFMTVJlJtmgCUUiIIysS2dZE8MR7Mm9u7vf2ag4cwx6fecpMIqPMwhPMpLN5ksVgkLtxok1GEw7jUpFUai82CxdGVQHMQOttIZTBYYNY7A4nC5LAAmADMMC8%20xgAHo6TBlOQEABrDHzbG41IE6m0hkUJAwNkcrE4lL4slWIn5UkEyl8%20mM5nC9kAsXcyWKgUqtlAA)

I have created `NotOne` utility type for negation purpose. As you see, nothing complicated, it just returns `never` if value is `1`.

Then, you need to make illegal state unrepresentable with union help `Data<T>`

Then, you need just use this union of two valid states to overloaded function.

Very similar example you can find in my [blog](https://catchts.com/type-negation#negation_overloadings)